# FLask-python: Dropdown selected value is not displayed when selected from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

In `test.html` has a id `testTime` and jinja2 template `time` (which is returned from test.py - render_template)

```
    <div>
        <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
        <option value=0>today</option>
        <option value=7>week</option>
        <option value=14>fortnight</option>
        <option value=30>month</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        {{ time }}
```

Script in html is,

```
function fetch_test_data(){
    let test = $("#testTime").val();
    axios({ 
        method:"get",
        url:"/test",
        params: {
            test
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $(document.body).html(response.data)
    }); 
}
```

Which send value to python file
`test.py`

```
        @app.route('/test', methods=["GET"])
        @login_required
        def transactions_view():
            time = (request.args.get("test"))

            print(time)  #this gives excepted output.

            return render_template("test.html", time=time)
```

This returns values from dropdown correctly.
And I'm rendering the `time` to `test.html` through jinja template `{{ time }}`.

But whenever value it's updated in html the `dropdown` refreshes without displaying the selected value.

Correct value is returned to flask and rendered back.But dropdown visualisation/list shows the first value instead of selected value?

How do modify so that selected value is displayed instead of default/first value?

**Edit:1**
What if `<select>` dropdown is prepopulated?
Here is my `html`

```
            <div>
               <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
                {% for option in options %}
                <option value={{ option }}>{{ option }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
                </div>
```

And `test.py` file

```
        @app.route('/test', methods=["GET"])
        @login_required
        def transactions_view():
            options = ["0","7","14","30"]

            return render_template("test.html", options=options)
```

In the above case how to use `selected` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add selected attribute.

```
<div>
    <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
    <option value=0 {% if time == 0 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>today</option>
    <option value=7 {% if time == 7 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>week</option>
    <option value=14 {% if time == 14 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>fortnight</option>
    <option value=30 {% if time == 30 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>month</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Added selected attribute still same response

Comment: instead of checking names please check ids, means for "today" I would have  {% if time == 0 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}

Comment: Made changes still same response

Comment: you should check what value {{time}} is holding and then check against that.
it might be 0 or "0" or today

Comment: Added an edit. How to do the same for prepopulated dropdown

Comment: Will this work?
    <option value="{{ option }}" {% if times == "{{ option }}" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}> {{ option }} </option>

Comment: by default from this  ["0","7","14","30"] which one you want to be selected?

Comment: "0". The first value

Comment: How to proceed from this?

Comment: Will this work? <option value="{{ option }}" {% if times == "{{ option }}" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}> {{ option }} </option>